# ruby change the value of an array

Tags: ruby

I haven't found a solution to my problem.

I have array like this

```
[Thu, 01 Oct 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00, "10 minutes", "Successful"]
[Mon, 06 Nov 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00, "8 minutes", "Successful"]
[Thu, 01 Dec 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00, "6 minutes", "Failed"]
```

etc

I want to replace "Successful" with "green", and "Failed" with "red".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your notation is difficult to understand. Please use the standard inspection format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.each do
  |a|
  a[2] =
  case a[2]
  when "Successful" then "green"
  when "Failed" then "red"
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you really format your code like this (block params on a new line, assignment RHS unindented on a new line)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which should be handy if there are more than two different substitutions:

```
a =[ ["Thu, 01 Oct 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00", "10 minutes", "Successful"],
     ["Mon, 06 Nov 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00", "8 minutes", "Successful"],
     ["Thu, 01 Dec 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00", "6 minutes", "Failed"] ]

lut = {"Successful" => "green",
       "Failed"     => "red"    }

a.each do |record|
  lut.each{|k,v| record[2][k] &&= v}
end

p a

# [["Thu, 01 Oct 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00", "10 minutes", "green"], ["Mon, 06 Nov 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00", "8 minutes", "green"], ["Thu, 01 Dec 2015 12:35:17 UTC +00:00", "6 minutes", "red"]]
```